# How to use Grafana dashboard variable in another variables regex?

Tags: regex, variables, grafana

I created a Grafana dashboard variable and tried to filter the values via the regex field. This works for static regex definition.

I would now like to use another variable inside the regex which provides the regex value.

So the regex field should look somehow like: `/$theRealRegexVar/`

I tried it with many different versions like `/${theRealRegexVar}/` or `/[[theRealRegexVar]]/` but it seems not to work.

Does it work somehow or is it simply impossible?

### Update

The datasource is prometheus.

The regex would be a regex ;-) (for example "^.*$" - however the user would provide it in the other variable)

Comment: What is used datasource and regexp value?

Answer (score 1):

Can I ask on the same subject if you can use a a variable in a regex for the next linked variable and so on.

So var1 is set
var2 runs the query but to limit results in the regex you use var1.
Something like this:
/csm-e-${var1}.*/

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32671940)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, if an answer is still relevant. But there are two options:

1. Use `$theRealRegexVar` directly in the query that delivers the values of your dashboard variable. For sure this only applies if your variable is a query.
2. Apply a format option on `$theRealRegexVar`, see https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/advanced-variable-format-options/. A similar task worked for me with `:raw`, so in your case put `${theRealRegexVar:raw}` into the regex field.